Markov chain conditional probability
Given a Markov chain $U -X-Y$, is it correct that $p(y|u) = \sum_x p(y|x) p(x|u)$. Intuitively, as $Y$ is only dependent on $X$ that should hold, I am unsure how to derive that from the Markov property $p(y|u,x) = p(y|x)$.

Yes, this is a version of the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation.
Let $(Z_0, Z_1, Z_2)$ be a Markov chain taking values in some finite or countable space. Then
\begin{align*}
P(Z_2&=y, Z_0=u)\\ 
&= \sum_{x} P(Z_2=y, Z_1=x, Z_0=u)\\
&= \sum_{x} P(Z_0=u)P(Z_1=x|Z_0=u)P(Z_2=y|Z_1=x, Z_0=u)\\
&= \sum_{x} P(Z_0=u)P(Z_1=x|Z_0=u)P(Z_2=y|Z_1=x),
\end{align*}
by the law of total probability and then the Markov property.
Now divide both sides by $P(Z_0=u)$ to get
$$
P(Z_2=y|Z_0=u)=\sum_{x}P(Z_1=x|Z_0=u)P(Z_2=y|Z_1=x)
$$
as required.
